# Trying to set the message in an IOException object

Tags: android

I have a class that loads in bitmaps and is in a `try{ }catch(IOException)` block.  I would like to throw my own exception if any of the methods return a null pointer. I cannot figure out how to set the message inside the IOException object.  It has a `getMessage` method but no `setMessage` method.

Code

```
inputStream=assetManager.open(name+".png");  
if (inputStream==null)
{
    IOException e=new IOException();
    e.m
    throw(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom message can be set via its constructor. Per java docs:

> IOException(String message) Constructs an IOException with the
>   specified detail message.

Example:

```
inputStream=assetManager.open(name+".png");  
if (inputStream==null)
{
    throw new IOException("my custom message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually just pass the message into the constructor

IOException e=new IOException("Something bad happened");